# SQR gives an error at NEW-PAGE command while printing a label

Tags: peoplesoft, sqr

I am running a SQR to print a label from PeopleSoft. I am getting an error at the end of the process. Strange this is my printer is printing a label perfectly but PeopleSoft process is giving an error so I put some logs and finally I found that it gives an error at NEW-PAGE command in my SQR.

Please let me know if anyone has any kind of suggestion.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens if you take the NEW-PAGE out?  Also, it would help to see code before and after the NEW-PAGE command.

Comment: I removed that command and it worked without any error. Will test with multiple labels and see how it works. Now, my concern is the functionality of NEW-PAGE command? Thank you.

Comment: From where are you calling the NEW-PAGE command? Is your header set?

Comment: Yes, this command is in my Header but it is the last line.